# .htaccess 301 redirect when %20 is in old url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect old url to new url but my url having "%20" between character like this

http://www.mydomainname.com/davey%20pumps.htm

This is old url and i want 301 redirection for this url to something other like

http://www.mydomainname.com/contactus

Comment: remove the space between davey and pumps

Comment: how does a url even have a space in it WITHOUT %20

Comment: Hi Shashank Sharma - can you show what you've tried so far, and describe whether it has worked or not?

Answer (score 0):

Using a double quoted uri pattern, you can redirect old uri with %20 to a new location. Add the following line to your .htaccess :

```
Redirect 301 "/foo%20bar" http://example.com/new
```

This will redirect **/foo%20bar** to **http://example.com/new** .

Answer (score 0):

In your Redirect 301, the first slug should have two things changed:

1. In the URL slug, convert the %20 to spaces (literally type a space with space bar)
2. Then, wrap the URL slug that contains spaces with quotes

This results in the following syntax for a single 301 redirect with a URL slug that contains %20 spaces.

```
Redirect 301 "/foo bar" http://example.com/new
```

In this scenario, the old page HTTP://example.com/foo%20bar redirects to the new page HTTP://example.com/new